# Blazor Authentication doesn't recognize the user as authenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

****UPDATE: I found the solution, and it's really stupid. I messed up my loading order in my Startup.cs, the Sessionstorage service has to be loaded before the authenticationstateprovider!**

We have an existing (internal use only) Website created with Blazor Server and initially .NET 5 (by now updated to .NET 6).
When I took the project to extend the functionality of the website the whole authentication was already implemented and working.
After adding some more functionality and releasing the first version of the website, the autentication stopped working and threw the following error: `*{"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider' to type 'WMS.Services.AuthService'."}*`
The implementation of the Authentication is how most tutorials show you how to do it for blazor server (using AuthenticationService and inheriting from it in a Custom class (AuthService in my case),generating an authenticationstate with ClaimsIdentity, using @attribute [Authorize] and all that).
I had no changes in these classes and still no explanation why it used to work and suddenly stopped working and started throwing that cast error (maybe an update within the .Net framework? I usually don't check the changelog before updating, probably should to that more often).

I managed to fix the error by using ServerAuthenticationStateProvider instead, which is an AuthenticationStateProvider intended for use in server-side Blazor which inherits from AuthenticationStateProvider (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.server.serverauthenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
The problem that remains is that the authentication still isn't working, even though when debugging, I can see that a user is there and everything's apparently working as intended, my router always thinks the user isn't authorized and always ends in the NotAuthorized section, thus leading to the login mask only refreshing and not being replaced with the actual content of the site (which is only allowed to be viewed by authenticated users).

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<CascadingAuthenticationState>  
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @{
                            var returnUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
                            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                    <Authorizing>
                        Loading...
                    </Authorizing>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

That's the implementation of the custom authenticationstateprovider called AuthService:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using WMS.Models.Auth;

namespace WMS.Services
{
    public class AuthService : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private const string USER_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY = "user_session_obj";

        private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _protectedSessionStore;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthService(ProtectedSessionStorage protectedSessionStore, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
            (this._protectedSessionStore, this._httpContextAccessor) = (protectedSessionStore, httpContextAccessor);

        public string IpAddress => _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

        private LoginUser User { get; set; }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            // read a possible user session object from the storage.
            var userSession = await GetUserSession();

            if (userSession != null)
                return await GenerateAuthenticationState(userSession);
            return await GenerateEmptyAuthenticationState();
        }

        public async Task LoginAsync(LoginUser user)
        {
            // store the session information in the client's storage.
            await SetUserSession(user);

            // notify the authentication state provider.
             SetAuthenticationState(GenerateAuthenticationState(user));
            //NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GenerateAuthenticationState(user));
        }

        public async Task LogoutAsync()
        {
            // delete the user's session object.
            await SetUserSession(null);

            // notify the authentication state provider.
            SetAuthenticationState(GenerateEmptyAuthenticationState());
            //NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GenerateEmptyAuthenticationState());
        }

        public async Task<LoginUser> GetUserSession()
        {
            if (User != null)
                return User;

            //string localUserJson = await _protectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>(USER_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY);
            string localUserJson = (await _protectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>(USER_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY)).Value;

            // no active user session found!
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localUserJson))
                return null;

            try
            {
                return RefreshUserSession(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginUser>(localUserJson));
            }
            catch
            {
                // user could have modified to local value, leading to an
                // invalid decrypted object. Hence, the user just did destory
                // his own session object. We need to clear it up.
                await LogoutAsync();
                return null;
            }
        }

        private async Task SetUserSession(LoginUser user)
        {
            // buffer the current session into the user object,
            // in order to avoid fetching the user object from JS.
            RefreshUserSession(user);

            await _protectedSessionStore.SetAsync(USER_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
            var test = await GetUserSession();
        }

        private LoginUser RefreshUserSession(LoginUser user) => User = user;

        private static Task<AuthenticationState> GenerateAuthenticationState(LoginUser user)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            }, "apiauth_type");
            claimsIdentity.AddClaims(user.Grants.Select(a => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, a)));

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            var test = new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal);
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }

        private static Task<AuthenticationState> GenerateEmptyAuthenticationState() => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal()));
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;
using System.Net.Http;
using Blazored.SessionStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using WMS.Helpers;
using WMS.Models.SteigerDb;
using WMS.Services;

namespace WMS
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get;}

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
            services.AddSingleton<ExceptionHelper>();
            services.AddSingleton<HttpService>();

            services.AddScoped<StateContainer>();
            services.AddScoped<ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, AuthService>();
         
            services.AddTransient<APIService>();
            services.AddTransient<ShippingOrderService>();
            services.AddTransient<InventoryService>();
            services.AddTransient<CommonService>();
            services.AddTransient<MovementService>();
            services.AddTransient<STEIGERDBContext>();
            services.AddTransient(sp =>
            {
                var httpService = sp.GetRequiredService<HttpService>();
                var iConfiguration = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                return new PickOrderGenerator(httpService, iConfiguration);
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddEventAggregator(options => options.AutoRefresh = true);
            services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
            services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage(); 
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var licenseKey = Configuration["SyncFusionLicenseKey"];
            Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense(licenseKey);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[GenerateAuthenticationState successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMVjs.png)

After the step from the screenshot (GenerateAuthenticationState) I'm calling LoginAsync which callsthe method SetAuthenticationState(GenerateAuthenticationState(user)) from the ServerAuthenticationStateProvider and has the following implementation:

```
   public void SetAuthenticationState(Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask)
        {
            _authenticationStateTask = authenticationStateTask ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationStateTask));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(_authenticationStateTask);
        }
```

So this simply notifies that the authenticationstate has changed, only that it somehow doesn't in my case.

I'd really appreciate some help because I'm at my wits end, this is my first blazor project so I'm no expert in blazor unfortunately and none of my collegues have any experience with blazor.
In case I missed some Code or Information, please ask and I'll provide it.

Comment: Well, if on the client-side you can see the user logged in, this might be a problem with `GetAuthenticationStateAsync`. I do not think that you should generate a new auth state if the user is logged in...

Comment: I am checking whether the user is logged in, and only generate a new auth state if there's no user logged in currently ( within GetAuthenticationStateAsync I am calling GetUserSession, there's my check if a user is already logged in or not)

Comment: Same issue here : in debug, I can see that my user is Authenticated, but I always hit the `NotAuthorized` code from `AuthorizedView`. I'm really interested by the solution of this one...